# inequality of complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

How to prove
$$\left|\frac{a-b}{1-\bar{a}b}\right|<1,$$

where $a,b$ are complex numbers, $\bar{a}$ is the complex conjugate of $a$, and $|a|,|b|<1$.

Comment: How to prove what?

Comment: I edited the post. Apologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that $\left|\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\bar{\alpha}\beta}\right| < 1$ when $|\alpha|,|\beta| < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506058/show-that-left-frac-alpha-beta1-bar-alpha-beta-right-1-when)

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373003/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/485960/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1630930/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1190613/42969 – all found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft%7C%5Cfrac%7Ba-b%7D%7B1-%5Cbar%7Ba%7Db%7D%5Cright%7C%3C1%2C%24&p=1)

Comment: how to find duplicate questions?

Comment: @alFeraas: With Approach0 (the link is at the end of my previous comment). See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24978/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$|a-b|^{2} -|1-\overline {a} b|^{2}=[|a|^{2}+|b|^{2}-2Re (\overline {a} b)]-[1+|a|^{2}|b|^{2} -2Re (\overline {a} b)]$$ $$=-(1-|a|^{2})(1-|b|^{2}) <0$$.

Comment: This has been asked and answered so often ...