# Prove that $|z - w| < |1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|$ is eqiuvalent to condition $(|z| < 1 \land |w| < 1) \lor (|z| > 1 \land |w| > 1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Edited: Key first step at the bottom, link to full solution provided in first comment.**

I'm struggling to show that complex numbers inequality:
$$
|z - w| < |1 - z\cdot \overline{w}| \quad z, w \in \mathbb{C}, \quad \overline{w}=Re(w) - i\cdot Im(w)
$$
is equivalent to condition below:
$$
(|z| < 1 \land |w| < 1) \lor (|z| > 1 \land |w| > 1)
$$
So far I used $|z-w|=|w-z| \rightarrow |z-w|+|w-z|<2\cdot |1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|$  representation to get:
$$
\sqrt {(z-w)\cdot \overline{(z-w)}}+\sqrt {(w-z)\cdot \overline{(w-z)}}<
2\cdot \sqrt {(1 - z\cdot \overline{w})\cdot \overline{(1-z\cdot \overline{w})}}
$$
which didn't really lead anywhere, but: $|z-w|+|w-z|<2\cdot |1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|$ with triangle inequality leads to:
$$
0=|z-w+w-z|\le ||z-w|+|w-z|<2\cdot |1 - z\cdot \overline{w}| \rightarrow 0<|1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|
$$
So, if I'm correct, I got to:
$$
0<|1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|
$$
Now, that $|x|=\sqrt {x\cdot \overline{x}}$,
$$
0< \sqrt{(1 - z\cdot \overline{w})\cdot \overline{(1-z \cdot \overline{w})}}
= \sqrt{(1 - z\cdot \overline{w})\cdot (\overline{1}-\overline{z} \cdot \overline{\overline{w}})}
$$
Ultimately, I receive:
$$
0<\sqrt{(1 - z\cdot \overline{w})\cdot (1-\overline{z} \cdot w)}
$$
Which after squaring both sides takes form:
$$
0<(1 - z\cdot \overline{w})\cdot (1-\overline{z} \cdot w)
$$
Not sure how to proceed though or even if it's the right direction.

**Edited:
Disregard the above, the key is to notice that:**
$$
|z - w|= (z-w)(\overline{z}-\overline{w})
$$
$$
|1-z \cdot \overline{w}|=(1-z \cdot \overline{w}) \cdot (1-\overline{z} \cdot w)
$$
as seen in: [Inequalty with complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373003/inequalty-with-complex-numbers) provided in first comment.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/373003/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506058/42969

Comment: The “trick” is to compute $|1 - z\cdot \overline{w}|^2 - |z-w|^2$, as you can see, e.g., here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/373016/42969.